# How to control published property value update in viewmodel in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, combine

I have a view model class with multiple `@Published` properties.

```
class AddPassaround : ObservableObject {
    @Published var name: String = ""
    @Published var reversed : String = ""
    @Published var password: String = ""
    @Published var age: String = ""
    @Published var address: String = ""
    @Published var oneAnotherProperty: String = ""

    init() {
    }
}
```

Whenever any one of the `@Published` property is updated, I call an API. Now there is another scenario that needs to update multiple `@Published` properties at once programmatically. Something like this

```
viewModel.name = "test"
viewModel.password = "newPassword"
viewModel.oneAnotherProperty = "notUpdateAll"
```

Now the problem is the API is called multiple times and view is reloaded multiple times. How can I make the API to call only once in this case only. It should work normally in other cases.

Comment: You want to trigger the api once whenever any of the 3 properties changes?

Comment: There are many logics using these properties. Now I have a method to change multiple properties at once.

Comment: Without a Minimal Reproducible Example that include the all the limitations and requierments we can only guess.

Comment: @David.C I want something like `viewModel.stopPublishing(); viewModel.name = ...; viewModel.password = ...; viewModel.test = ....; viewModel.publishNow()`

Comment: @loremipsum I'm looking for something like `UITableView`'s `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` method

Comment: @arunsiva that isn't possible with `@Published`. There are more elaborate ways if achieving what you want. But it all sums up to removing the wrapper and controlling updates.

Comment: @arunsiva see below I added an option for substituting `@Published`

Answer (score 2):

SwiftUI faces the same problem you face: when you update three separate `@Published` properties of your `ObservableObject`, SwiftUI gets notified three times.

SwiftUI avoids updating the UI three times by coalescing the events. On the first notification, SwiftUI arranges to be awakened before the run loop waits for the next event. On the later notifications, SwiftUI sees that it's already arranged to be awakened and does nothing.

UIKit, AppKit, and Core Animation also coalesce display updates; this is what methods like [`UIView.setNeedsDisplay`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622437-setneedsdisplay) and [`CALayer.setNeedsDisplay`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410855-setneedsdisplay) are for.

You can use the same sort of coalescing. One way to do it is to use `NotificationQueue`:

- In `init`, subscribe to a private `Notification.Name` and sender. When the notification arrives, call the API.
- Also in `init`, subscribe to `objectWillChange` outputs. When `objectWillChange` sends an output, ask `NotificationQueue.default` to enqueue the private notification.
- Pass the `.onName` and `.onSender` coalescing flags to the `NotificationQueue`, so that it only sends the notification once per turn of the event loop.

```
class AddPassaround : ObservableObject {
    @Published var name: String = ""
    @Published var reversed : String = ""
    @Published var password: String = ""
    @Published var age: String = ""
    @Published var address: String = ""
    @Published var oneAnotherProperty: String = ""

    private var tickets: [AnyCancellable] = []
    private let notificationSender = NSObject()
    private var notificationName: Notification.Name { .init("AddPassaround call API") }

    init() {
        NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: notificationName, object: notificationSender)
            .sink { [weak self] _ in self?.callAPI() }
            .store(in: &tickets)

        objectWillChange
            .sink { [weak self] _ in self?.scheduleCallAPI() }
            .store(in: &tickets)
    }

    private func scheduleCallAPI() {
        // Arrange to callAPI soon, if I haven't already arranged it.
        NotificationQueue.default.enqueue(
            .init(name: notificationName, object: notificationSender),
            postingStyle: .whenIdle,
            coalesceMask: [.onName, .onSender],
            forModes: [.common]
        )
    }

    private func callAPI() {
        print("this is where you call the API")
    }
}
```

We use a separate object, `notificationSender`, instead of `self`, to avoid a retain cycle between `self` and `NotificationCenter.default`.

If you only want a few of your properties to trigger an API call, you can give them `willSet` (or `didSet`) observers instead of subscribing to `objectWillChange`:

```
class AddPassaround : ObservableObject {
    @Published var name: String = "" {
        willSet { scheduleCallAPI() }
    }

    @Published var reversed : String = ""

    @Published var password: String = "" {
        willSet { scheduleCallAPI() }
    }

    @Published var age: String = ""
    @Published var address: String = ""
    @Published var oneAnotherProperty: String = ""

    private var tickets: [AnyCancellable] = []
    private let notificationSender = NSObject()
    private var notificationName: Notification.Name { .init("AddPassaround call API") }

    init() {
        NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: notificationName, object: notificationSender)
            .sink { [weak self] _ in self?.callAPI() }
            .store(in: &tickets)
    }

    private func scheduleCallAPI() {
        // Arrange to callAPI soon, if I haven't already arranged it.
        NotificationQueue.default.enqueue(
            .init(name: notificationName, object: notificationSender),
            postingStyle: .whenIdle,
            coalesceMask: .onName,
            forModes: [.common]
        )
    }

    private func callAPI() {
        print("this is where you call the API")
    }
}
```